# Servo with Arduino

Tags: arduino, pwm, servo

this is not my first time that work with servo motor on arduino mega adk, but this time something went wrong! I'm connecting my servo Motor to an arduino as it should be. and then I wrote my code as mentioned here:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo monServo;

void setup()
{
    monServo.attach(7, 1000, 2000);
    monServo.write(45);
} 
void loop()
{ 
}
```

but my servo doesn't work correctly, it doesn't turn 45° but it turn into it's max value and then begin to make noise as it wants to turn more. I thought that the problem is from the servo motor but I tried this with 3 different motors but the same result. From where this issue is comming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an issue with the power supply. Try powering the Arduino with a wall power supply instead of using the USB port. You can also add a large capacitor in series with the servo. [See "If the servo misbehaves"](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-14-servo-motors/if-the-servo-misbehaves)

Comment: powering the servo from a wall power supply instead of GND and VCC from arduino will it solve the problem?

Comment: No, powering the Arduino through the DC port. Check the link.

Comment: I will check then

Comment: @Gabriele good advice, but next time try to use the `edit` button to update your answer, instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Oh I did not think about it and I'm new to stack. I'll try next time, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the additional two parameters in the *attach* method: substitute `monServo.attach(7, 1000, 2000);` with `monServo.attach(7);`

Comment: I did it, same problem :(

Comment: Can you add a diagram of the circuit?

Comment: here is the [link](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/rosserial_arduino(2f)Tutorials(2f)Servo(20)Controller.html)

Comment: You can try changing pin to see if the problem persists. You can also try adding a delay after monServo.attach(7);

Comment: I've tried with all pwm pins but the same behaviour